# NVD3 Cumulative Line Chart : How to save Line Chart as image

Tags: jquery, d3.js, nvd3.js, linechart, cumulative-line-chart

I am using `NVD3 Cumulative Line Chart`,it works perfect for me but i want to save that graph as image(Like Screen Capturing). For that I have tried `html2canvas` but it does not save image same as graph. As shown in below image.

[image]

**I want image same as Generated Line Chart**.So please show me way for that.

Answer (score 1):

You want to save an SVG as an image since NVD3 uses D3 and D3 uses SVG.

These might help you get started:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6466603 (from the master himself)

http://techslides.com/save-svg-as-an-image

Comment: `@Lucas` thanks for valuable response. but i am still didn't get image from svg. can you please help me to generate image from this http://nvd3.org/examples/cumulativeLine.html line chart.